# What is the nestjs error handling approach (business logic error vs. http error)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, nestjs

While using NestJS to create API's I was wondering which is the best way to handle errors/exception.
I have found two different approaches :

1. Have individual services and validation pipes `throw new Error()`, have the controller `catch` them and then throw the appropriate kind of `HttpException`(`BadRequestException`, `ForbiddenException` etc..)
2. Have the controller simply call the service/validation pipe method responsible for handling that part of business logic, and throw the appropriate `HttpException`.

There are pros and cons to both approaches:

1. This seems the right way, however, the service can return `Error` for different reasons, how do I know from the controller which would be the corresponding kind of `HttpException` to return?
2. Very flexible, but having `Http` related stuff in services just seems wrong.

I was wondering, which one (if any) is the "nest js" way of doing it?

How do you handle this matter?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Let's assume your business logic throws an `EntityNotFoundError` and you want to map it to a `NotFoundException`.

For that, you can create an [`Interceptor`](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) that transforms your errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // next.handle() is an Observable of the controller's result value
    return next.handle()
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof EntityNotFoundError) {
          throw new NotFoundException(error.message);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      }));
  }
}
```

You can then use it by adding `@UseInterceptors(NotFoundInterceptor)` to your controller's class or methods; or even as a global interceptor for all routes. Of course, you can also map multiple errors in one interceptor.

Try it out in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/7zw47o8961?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts).

Comment: Note, that the code snippet already uses the new nest v6 interceptor. For an v5 example, have a look at the codesandbox.

Comment: The nestjs exception filter looks more adapted for that job
https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: While this works, it should not be the accepted answer. As @AlexandreMorgaut mentioned, Nest's ExceptionFilters are meant for this exact use case.

Answer (score 25):

Nest Js provides an exception filter that handles error not handled in the application layer, so i have modified it to return 500, internal server error for exceptions that are not Http. Then logging the exception to the server, then you can know what's wrong and fix it.

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter, HttpException, HttpStatus, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class HttpErrorFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  private readonly logger : Logger 
  constructor(){
    this.logger = new Logger 
  }
  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost): any {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();

    const statusCode = exception instanceof HttpException ? exception.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    const message = exception instanceof HttpException ?  exception.message || exception.message?.error: 'Internal server error'

    const devErrorResponse: any = {
      statusCode,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
      method: request.method,
      errorName: exception?.name,
      message: exception?.message
    };

    const prodErrorResponse: any = {
      statusCode,
      message
    };
    this.logger.log( `request method: ${request.method} request url${request.url}`, JSON.stringify(devErrorResponse));
    response.status(statusCode).json( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? devErrorResponse: prodErrorResponse);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice implementation! I think you can also use NestJS dependency injection syntax, so you don't have to declare a private property "logger" and then instantiate it. You can just use "private readonly logger : Logger" inside the constructor and it is instantiated automatically.

Comment: Thank you, 
noted will implement and update the answer.

Comment: At least for my use case, this is the best answer.

Comment: FYI  @MarcusCastanho - it seems you can't use NestJS DI, at least when using a global filter -- because you have to instantiate the filter yourself.

Comment: To return the correct error message you need to do something like this: 
```const message = exception instanceof HttpException ? exception.getResponse()?.['message'] ? exception.getResponse()?.['message'] : exception['message'] : 'Internal server error';```

Comment: @LuscaDev I don't think anybody ever should do something like this. At least not the way you posted, it's impossible to read.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to bind services not only to HTTP interface, but also for GraphQL or any other interface. So it is better to cast business-logic level exceptions from services to Http-level exceptions (BadRequestException, ForbiddenException) in controllers.

In the simpliest way it could look like

```ts
import { BadRequestException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class HttpHelperService {
  async transformExceptions(action: Promise<any>): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return await action;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === 'QueryFailedError') {
        if (/^duplicate key value violates unique constraint/.test(error.message)) {
          throw new BadRequestException(error.detail);
        } else if (/violates foreign key constraint/.test(error.message)) {
          throw new BadRequestException(error.detail);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then

Comment: Thanks Alex. How would you use the code you posted? In the controller?

Comment: How did you implement this service?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a factory or handler to when controller catch the exception (error or domain error) its map it to another HttpException.

```
@Controller('example')
export class ExampleController {

  @Post('make')
  async make(@Res() res, @Body() data: dataDTO): Promise<any> {
   
    try {
      //process result...
       return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(result);
    } catch (error) {
      throw AppErrorHandler.createHttpException(error); //<---here is the error type mapping
    };
  };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you try to send a bad request error, the below code might help you:**

```
import { Controller, Post, UploadedFiles, UseInterceptors, Body, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';



@Post('/multiple')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
  async uploadFiles(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>, @Body() body: any) {
    console.log('body :', body);
    if (!files || !files.length) {
      throw new BadRequestException('files should have at least one object');
    }
    const req: FileDataReq = {
      files,
      ...body,
    };
    return req;
  }
```