# How to @Catch() an interface in a NestJS filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, nestjs

I'm working on a NestJS backend that uses Firebase for authentication.
I want to catch all and only the exception from Firebase (for example when users use an expired token) and translate them to actual HTTP errors. I want the `HttpExceptions` to be handled by the default filter.

I tried creating a new filter, but when I try to set the decorator like
`@Catch(FirebaseError)` it doesn't compile saying `'FirebaseError' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`
I also tried leaving the `@Catch()` without arguments and specifing the `FirebaseError` type on in the `catch` function, but it catches every exception.

```typescript
// This code doesn't work
import { FirebaseError } from 'firebase';
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch(FirebaseError)
export class FirebaseExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter<FirebaseError> {
  catch(exception: FirebaseError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    // handle the exception
  }
}
```

I want this filter to be called for `FirebaseError` exceptions, but if I write `@Catch(FirebaseError)` it doesn't compile, if I write `@Catch()` it catches every exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/845c5df66fbd0190b5e85e46d31868a1240c431c/packages/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.ts#L35) of `ExceptionFilter`:

```
ExceptionMetatype => exception instanceof ExceptionMetatype,
```

`instanceof` checks do not work on interfaces, only on classes. (It needs the prototype information on runtime.)

---

You could use an `Interceptor` to transform the errors to `HttpExceptions` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238420/4694994). (Of course, here you also cannot use `instanceof` with the interface.)

Comment: That was the right way! I used an Interceptor and the `name` attribute of the `FirebaseError` interface instead of `instanceof`

Comment: Hey Carlovan and @Kim Kern, can you share that interceptor code, I'm stuck at it.

Comment: @DeepanshuDemla Have you had a look at the linked answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238420/4694994